# Collections.max not working in a loop: "java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, collections

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList <Integer> seq = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int iterations = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a number sequence(no spaces, only commas)");
    String j = kbReader.nextLine();
    kbReader = new Scanner(j);
    kbReader.useDelimiter("\\D");

    //adds input to array list
    while(kbReader.hasNextInt())
    {
        int i = kbReader.nextInt();
        seq.add(i);
    }

    while(seq.size() > 0)
    {
        //removes zeros and numbers behind
        if(seq.contains(0)) 
        {   
            int zeroSearch = seq.lastIndexOf(0);
            for(int c = zeroSearch; c >= 0; c--)
            {
                seq.remove(c);
            }
            iterations++;

        }   


        //number operations
        int largest = Collections.max(seq);
        int largeLoc = seq.lastIndexOf(largest);

        if(largest % 2 == 0)
        {
            largest = largest -2;
            iterations++;
        }
        else
        {
            largest--;
            iterations++;
        }
        seq.set(largeLoc, largest);
    }

    System.out.println(iterations + "moves" required);
}
```

For some reason, the max method will not work in this loop and returns the error "java.util.NoSuchElementException". The directions read **"Given a number sequence, remove all the zeros, if any, and all the digits to their left. Then find the largest remaining digit and if it is even subtract 2 from it or if it is odd subtract 1 from it. If two or more digits become tied as the largest digit, use the rightmost digit as the largest. Repeat the application of the rules to the sequence. How many moves were required to delete the sequence?"**

Comment: The java documantation says "Throws: NoSuchElementException - if the collection is empty". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)

Comment: The javadoc states "NoSuchElementException - if the collection is empty." My guess is it's empty.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a case where you go read the javadoc for `java.util.Collections#max` to see why it would throw that:

> **Throws**:
>
> NoSuchElementException - if the collection is empty.

[Collections Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection))

So clearly `seq` is empty (meaning `kbReader` probably had nothing to read). Add debug to your code to see this more clearly (such as the input/output).

Comment: kbReader only reads at the beginning, not within the while loop where the array list is actually altered. The kbReader is just to add input into the array list, hence the "adds input to array list" comment.

Comment: Yes, and if it reads nothing, it will add nothing to the list. And then this exception will happen, because your list is empty.

Comment: Wrong. That error would only occur if the user enters nothing, whereas the error occurred with input. I've already tested the Scanner by printing out the user-inputted ArrayList, and it works fine. The problem was that within the large while-loop, after removing zeros for a couple iterations, there was no break statement to exit the loop once the size was zero, causing that error. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Nice find. Again, the reader being empty was only one plausible cause, the real cause (as stated) was you were passing an empty list. Debug is and always will be a good friend for finding these issues out.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm still a little shaky with debug, however.

Comment: My tip is instead of printing things like "1, 2, 3", print out variable information. E.g. you could have your loop print out the list each iteration, or print what is read when you read it, etc. Anything which could change the outcome (branching statement evaluations like for/while/if) or "code flow" is also worth printing sometimes